# ending na instead of ne, when to use it?

Tags: particles, sentence-final-particles, particle-な, particle-ね

which connotation gives to a phrase ending with "na" instead of "ne"? is it more informal or what?

Particulary saying,

"soo da naa" instead of "so desu ne"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`「な」`and　`「ね」` seem to be more rough sound and generally applies to the male gender but is not necessarily restricted to only males. You can think of it as "huh". e.g.

> 洋介：今、図書館に行くんだよ**な**。

Yousuke: You are going to the library now **huh**?

or

> ボブ：日本語は、たくさん勉強したけど**な**。まだ全然わからない。

Bob: I studied Japanese a lot, **right**? But, I still don't get it at all.

In your case, `「そうだな」` or `「そうですね」` would roughly mean "Is that so, huh?"